# Gradle ignores private Nexus repository when searching for dependencies

Tags: maven, gradle, nexus

I am trying to pull some internal dependencies from a private Nexus repository. But when I build the project, gradle does not search for the dependency in the private repo but looks for it in the maven repos.

I did some investigations and found that this is happening with only one project. Dependencies do get pulled in other projects. I still don't know why it is happening.

This is how I have added the repository:

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    maven { url 'https://ci-artifactory.corda.r3cev.com/artifactory/corda' }
    maven { url 'https://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs-releases' }

    maven {
        url 'http://private/repository/project'
        credentials {
            username = "user"
            password = "password"
        }
    }
}
```

dependency:

```
implementation 'com.project:project-1'
```

This is what gradle shows:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':workflows:compileKotlin'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':workflows:compileClasspath'.
   > Could not find project:0.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - file:/C:/Users/local/.m2/repository/com/project/directory/0.1-SNAPSHOT/project-1.pom
       - file:/C:/Users/local/.m2/repository/com/project/directory/0.1-SNAPSHOT/project-1.jar
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/project/directory/0.1-SNAPSHOT/project-1.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/project/directory/0.1-SNAPSHOT/project-1.jar
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/project/directory/0.1-SNAPSHOT/project-1.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/project/directory/0.1-SNAPSHOT/project-1.jar
       - https://software.r3.com/artifactory/corda/com/project/directory/0.1-SNAPSHOT/project-1.pom
       - https://software.r3.com/artifactory/corda/com/project/directory/0.1-SNAPSHOT/project-1.jar
       - https://jitpack.io/com/project/directory/0.1-SNAPSHOT/project-1.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/com/project/directory/0.1-SNAPSHOT/project-1.jar
```

It does not search in the private repository.

Comment: Can you please run the build with either `--info` or `--debug` (whatever works) and check whether Gradle tries to access the repository but gets rejected (HTTP 401)?

Comment: I think I found a solution to this while fiddling around. It seems like there was another repositories block. allProjects { repositories {} } Adding the urls in there worked

Comment: Nice to here! Maybe you can answer your own question so it may help others?

Comment: yep, answered :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The project I was working with had two gradle files, `repositories.gradle` & `build.gradle`

I was adding the nexus URL to repositories.gradle file in the `repositories` block. But the URL was not being searched for dependencies. After a bit of exploration I found that the build.gradle file also has a repositories block:

```
allProjects {

    . . . . . . . . . . 

    repositories {
        . . . . . . . . . . 
        . . . . . . . . . . 
    }
}
```

This seems to be overriding the repositories block in `repositories.gradle` file. When I added the nexus URL in here the dependencies were resolved.

Hope that helps anyone having a similar issue :)

Comment: Wow thank you! Same thing happened to me. settings.gradle.kts repositories were getting ignored

Answer (score 0):

As an updated information and solution for me was in the settings.gradle

There is another repositories block in dependencyResolutionManagement.